# Moving objects containing a running std::thread member

Tags: c++

How to correctly use the move semantic with running thread in object?

Sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    std::string v_;
    std::thread t_;

    void start() {
        t_ = std::thread(&A::threadProc, this);
    }

    void threadProc() {
        for(;;) {
            std::cout << "foo-" << v_ << '\n';
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    A m;
    {
        A a;
        a.v_ = "bar";
        a.start();
        m = std::move(a);
    }
    std::cout << "v_ = " << m.v_ << '\n'; /* stdout is 'v_ = bar' as expected    */
                                          /* but v_ in thread proc was destroyed */
                                          /* stdout in thread proc is 'foo-'     */
    m.t_.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use class members after moving, but when I go out scope, class members are destroyed and std::thread is moved into new object as expected but it starting use destroyed members.

It seems to me because of using `this` pointer in thread initialization.

What is best practice in this case?

Comment: For completeness, also a constructor, destructor and copy constructor should be defined as well. Whereas the copy constructor should be explicitly deleted in this case.

Comment: Hmm, not sure there's anything you can do about this. Can you revisit the requirement?

Comment: Does it not use default ctors? Anyway I have larger sample with debug output in ctors and dtor and behaver is same.

Comment: @fandyushin: Yes, the implicitly-defined move assignment operator will be invoked here. But you can't get around the fact that your thread is already invoking a member function on an object about to die.

Comment: This is a good question. Please improve the question's title so that other people can find it.

Comment: @FrankSchmid: No; don't define pointless methods.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I want to move object with runned thread into vector. I can initialize it in vector but I interesting how to move it.

Comment: @fandyushin: Your problem isn't in moving `A`, it's in moving the thing that a thread is already executing. I don't think you can do that.

Comment: The thread is executing the member function of `A`. As the previous instance of `A` is destructed after the move, the member pointer used by the thread gets invalid.
You could use a second independent object instance e.g. `B` (that is a member of A) to contain the function to be executed and move that to the new `A` instance.

Comment: @FrankSchmid: That sounds like an answer, not a comment - but a bad answer since a B member of A is _not_ independent of A; members die with the containing object. "Moving" an object doesn't move references to the object or its members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written, it's not going to work. After moving, the thread `m.t_` refers to a thread which is still running `a.threadProc()`. That will be attempting to print `a.v_`.

There are even two problems with the snippet: not only is `a.v_` moved from (so its value is unspecified), but it's also about to be destroyed in another thread, and that destruction is not sequenced-after its use.

Since the object needs to stay alive long enough, with a non-trivial lifetime due to the thread, you'll need to get it off the stack and out of the vector. Instead, use `std::shared_ptr` to manage the lifetime. You will probably need to pass that `shared_ptr` to the thread, to avoid a race condition where the object might expire before the thread starts running. You can't rely on `std:shared_from_this`.

Comment: Thanks, `shared_ptr` should help

Answer (score 3):

> What is best practice in this case?

The best practice is to delete the move constructor and move assignment operator to prevent this from happening.  Your object requires that `this` never changes, and you're getting undefined behavior because in this case the object was whipped out from beneath your thread and subsequently destroyed.

If, for whatever reason preventing moves goes against your design requirements, then there are a some common approaches that would make the most sense to anybody fortunate enough to be reading and maintaining your code.

1. Use the *pimpl idiom* to create an internal object dynamically which can move with the outer object.  The outer object is movable, but the inner object is not.  The thread is bound to that object, and anything the thread needs access to is also within that object.  In your case, you would basically take your structure as it is and wrap it.  The basic idea is something like:

   ```
   class MovableA
   {
   public:
       MovableA() : a_(std::make_unique<A>()) {}
       void start() { a_->start(); }
       A & a() const { return *a_; }
   private:
       std::unique_ptr<A> a_;
   };
   ```

   The benefit of this approach is that you can move `MoveableA` without needing to synchronize with the running thread.
2. Abandon the notion of using stack allocation, and just allocate `A` dynamically.  This has the same benefit as option 1, and is simpler because you're not having to wrap your class in anything or provide accessors.

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<A> m;
   {
       auto a = std::make_unique<A>();
       a->v_ = "bar";
       a->start();
       m = std::move(a);
   }
   std::cout << "v_ = " << m->v_ << '\n';
   m->t_.join();
   ```

I started writing an option 3 that avoids dynamic allocation and instead binds a 'floating' version of `this` to a `std::reference_wrapper` but I felt I'd get it wrong without thinking about it a lot, and it seemed hacky and horrible anyway.

The bottom line is if you want to keep the object outside your thread *and* use it in the thread, the best practice is to use dynamic allocation.

Comment: Pimpl is overhead in my case, anyway thanks for hint to delete move ctor in case of dependency on `this` pointer.

Answer (score 2):

(Alternative answer, using C++17)

Using lambda's, you can capture a copy of `A`. Since the thread owns the lambda and the lambda owns the copy, you don't have lifetime issues:

```
t_ = std::thread([*this](){threadProc();});
```

Comment: Is this invalid before C++17?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: AFAICT, yes, but `[tmp=*this]` might be C++14 (I'd have to check).

Comment: Okay, I guess what I meant was, please explain how this is invalid before C++17.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: Simple, it's invalid because C++14 does not have a grammar rule which produces such a capture list, nor a semantic rule that would give meaning to it.

Comment: So, more simply put, the ability to capture `*this` is new in C++17?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: Indeed.